# Do I need to chnage the autoload.php file for composer to work with symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I was using symfony vendors/install to update the new modules.
I have downloaded the module but i am confused with composer.

In my `deps` file i already have many new bundles which i have downloaded.

1. Now if i use composer how will those bundles gets updated. Do i need to convert the Deps equivalent file for composer.json.
2. Now do i also need to chnage my autoload.php file to use composer
3. If i need to install new bundle , then will my old bundles stay as it is which were installed with vendors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now if i use composer how will those bundles gets updated. Do i need to convert the Deps equivalent file for composer.json.

Your deps file needs to be converted into composer.json.

composer.lock is something similar to deps.lock and it's auto-generated. When running install command composer will use composer.lock to install locked versions. Running update command will update packages and store installed versions in composer.lock.

> Now do i also need to chnage my autoload.php file to use composer

Only if you transition from using vendors script to composer. You'll have to update your app/autoload.php file just once to include the file generated by composer. Look at an example in [symfony-standard](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/autoload.php) (master branch) or [here](https://github.com/KnpLabs/symfony-with-composer/blob/master/app/autoload.php).

Composer will regenerate the autoloader for you each time you run install or update command.

Comment: but what about the namespaces which are already there in old autoload.php. i have around 16 namespaces written there. what will happen if i dont convert the old deps file to composer.json. Did it delete something because i don't know how to convert

Comment: If you want to use composer, you have to replace deps file with composer.json. You should remove all namespaces already defined in your autoload.php. They're not needed as they'll be handled by composer.

Comment: is there any example of composer.json file which contain some extra bundles so that i can look at how they added extra bundles. so you mean that i don't need to add namespaces if i start using composer?

Comment: You might try looking it up (random result from google: https://gist.github.com/2488761) but it's really simple. Just add your bundles the same way standard bundles were added (see examples). Also. read docs for composer here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/ look for package names on packagist.org

Comment: I have added `tcpdf/tcpdf:"dev-master"` in require section in `composer.json` and composer updated. The dir is created, but how to create an tcpdf instance in AppKernel?